# Teradata SQL - Please look at the Body and provide me the logic for the solution

Tags: sql, database, teradata

[image]

Need Teradata logic for the above scenario. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select id, max(flag) as flag
from t
group by id;
```